# Происхождение слов "тапки" и "тапочки".

Tags: словообразование

Если **"тапки"**, то разве не **"тапы"** были вначале, как что-то более серьезное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Беседа не слишком энергично идёт, поэтому позволю себе добавить, что татарское ТАПИ само связано с топанием (тапи-тапи, тапарга и др.) - то есть все эти слова происходят от древнего звукоподражания топ-топ.

Answer (score 2):

*"Тапки"* произошло от слова *"топать"* и не обязательно через *"тапы"*, а скорее всего, напрямую: конень ***"топ"*** + суффикс ***"к"*** + окончание ***"а"*** (со сменой гласной в корне нового слова, так как нет суффикса *"а"*). Получилось слово *"тапка"* (ед.ч.), а от него *"тапки"* (мн.ч.).

А слово ***"топать"*** есть у Фасмера:

> Из звукоподражат.; ср.: сербохорв.
> топо̀тати «топать», словенск. topòt
> (род. п. topóta) «топот, стук».
> Связано чередованием гласных с тепу́
> (см.), болг. те́пам «топаю, бью». Ср.
> также: лит. tарšt, межд. «шлеп, хлоп»,
> tàpšterėti «хлопнуть», латышск. tара,
> tарu, межд. «топ, топ!», tарat
> «шагать, топать», лит. tарuоti — то
> же.

Comment: >Тапки" произошло от слова "топать"   

Есть доказательства?
Версия правдоподобная, но я не нашел ни малейшего подтверждения в источниках.

Comment: Я, как и вы, не нашёл никакой этимологии слова тапки. Но версия, которую я изложил, кажется очень убедительной.

Comment: Я нашёл в своем ответе грубую ошибку. Слово "тапок" неграмотно.  Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: А зачем об этом кричать?)))
Это уже не грубая ошибка. Максимум - просторечие. Язык меняется....

Comment: to @Валентин 

Даже не грубая и совсем не ошибка. http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F2%E0%EF%EA%E0

Comment: Офигеть. "тапка" объявляется просторечием.
Да здравствует Вики, самая свободная от достоверности энциклопедия!

Тем не менее ориентироваться всё-таки следует на более авторитетные источники. А они пока что дают нормативным вартнтом именно "тапка", а "тапок" - просторечно-разговорным.

Comment: "Тапок" тоже разговорное на Википедии.

Comment: Я об этом:

>Синонимы1.тапочек; тапка (прост.)

Answer (score 1):

> "Тапки" произошло от слова "топать".

Не зря же для детей это "топики" или "топ-топы". Часто можно слышать от родителей:"Где наши топ-топы? Сейчас обуемся и пойдём гулять."

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, кому-то будет интересно узнать,что в татарском языке "тәпи" означает "лапа,лапка (животного)" и "ножка (ребёнка)". А слово "тәпиләү" значит "идти пешком" или "ходить (о детях)"

Answer (score 0):

Интересно, что "tapes" в древнегреческом означало "ковёр".
Возможно, это тоже связано с топанием.

Answer (score -1):

Очень поверхностное отнесение; тапочки от слова "топать".
выше уже было дано верное направление: тапочки от татарского слова "тапи", что означает маленькая ножка у девушки, у ребёнка, а также котенка. 
В старину славяне носили лапти. Это общеизвестно. Татары носили кожаные сапоги (итек-читек). Отсюда в русском у донских козаков слово "ичиыги". Это удобно для поездок верхом на лошади (недаром до недавнего времени все военнослужащие Хходили в сапогах. Это очень удобно. Я сам служил, и после армии было непривычно переходить на туфли и ботинки.   А детям шили "тапиляу", тапочки. У татар и сейчас есть выражение "тапи-тапи", что означает "ходить пешком". Общеизвестны выражения: "Тапарга" (топтать ногами); "тапап китерга" (пройти по кому-то, чему-то ногами).

Практически вся одежда была перенята русскими от татар, вплоть до русского  сарафана, шубы, кафтана, юбки, башмаков,епанчи, и т. д. 
Исконная одежда у русских - рубаха - от слова "рубить", лапоть - от слова "лапа" (вот основная обувь крестьянина, а не тапочки).

То, что русский народ быстро воспринимал удобство и надежность одежды и обуви у других народов, и привело его к дальнейшему развитию. Так он безоговорочно стал старшим братом в единой семье народов России, а затем СССР.

ТО же самое широкое заимствование русский народ произвел у татар и в приготовлении различных блюд. Но это уже другая история.

Comment: Время упоительных историй. Слава богу, в этот раз обошлось без "поскреби русского — найдёшь татарина". А ссылки на авторитетные источники, подтверждающие "общеизвестные" факты, можно увидеть?